# Django POST form validation to an another page

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a TV show manager with Django and I have a problem with form validation and redirection.
I have a simple page with a form where people can search a Tv show, and an other page where the result of the query is displaying. (for the query I'm using the API of TVDB I don't know if its useful)
What I want to do is:

1. If I submit the form and there are errors display the form with related erros
2. If the form is valid go to the other page with the data to make the query with the API

**forms.py**

```
class SearchShowForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        required=True,
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Search'})
    )
```

**views.py**

```
def step1(request):
        form = SearchShowForm()
        context = {'form': form, 'step': 1}
        return render(request, 'tvshows_manager/step_1.html', context)

def step2(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchShowForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return render(request, 'tvshows_manager/step_2.html', {'data': form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            return render(request, 'tvshows_manager/step_1.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/step_1/')
```

**template for step_1.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'step2' %}" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" class="btn btn-default">
    <div class="search-form-input">
        {{ form.query }}
    </div>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Ce champs est nécessaire</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

At the moment if I'm going to the step1 page and I submit a blank input the page 'step2' is displaying with the form and errors and I want to stay to the step1 page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your description and views.py, you stay on step 2 that's why:

1. User is on page '/step_1/'
2. He submit form
3. Because action param in form is point to '/step_2/', it's going to that url
4. In view request.method == 'POST' is True, but form is not valid.
5. You are rendering template from '/step_1', but not redirecting User.

So here is sample fix:

```
def step2(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchShowForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return render(request, 'tvshows_manager/step_2.html', {'data': form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/step_1/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/step_1/')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is it possible to display errors messages on the 'step_1' page if the form is invalid ?

Comment: @Remyr yes, you can do it with messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/

e.g. `messages.error(request, 'Document deleted.')`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for! I learned a new thing about django that's cool! :)